# What is an example of Euclidean Space $R$ with a total system {$\phi_{n}$} which is not complete?

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality

What is an example of Euclidean Space $R$ with a total system {$\phi_{n}$} which is not complete?

A total system {$\phi_{n}$} is an orthogonal system {$\phi_{n}$} in $R$ such that there is not nonzero element orthogonal to every $\phi_{n}$.

I know $R$ has not to be complete, and I think $C_{[a,b]}^{(2)}$ of all continuous functions with the scalar product $$(f,g)=\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx$$ with the usual operations could work. Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483455/example-of-complete-orthonormal-set-in-an-inner-product-space-whose-span-is-not